# Postgres: Event trigger for logging all dbs changes to one table

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I am trying to create an generic event trigger, which I set up in every future databases, I create. This trigger should update the main db's table every time one of the other databases have add or dropped a table.

I use postgres 12. I have the main database called `main_db`.
I have created a table in `main_db` called `table` with columns a, b and c. This table is the one, all event triggers should update with the infomation about the tablename, the db it was created in and when.

I have managed to do a log table like described above in the same db as tables where created and dropped. I used https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-event-triggers-postgresql as an guideline for setting up the event trigger.

My code which works in the same db as the changes happens:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() RETURNS event_trigger AS $$ 
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN 
    IF TG_TAG = 'CREATE TABLE' 
    THEN r:=pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
    INSERT INTO tabletest(a, b, c) VALUES (val1, val2, val3);
    END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Event trigger:
`CREATE EVENT TRIGGER event_trigger ON ddl_command_end EXECUTE FUNCTION func()`

I have tried to:
Change `INSERT INTO tabletest` to `INSERT INTO table` and `INSERT INTO schema.table`. Both fails. The table is not found.

However, the event trigger in the "child" database will not update the table in the main db.

Can anybody tell me, what I am missing? Is it possible? Should I do something else instead?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing; could you include a script that reproduces the situation, including all DDL?

Comment: @mustaccio, thank you for answering. I have tried to rewrite my question. Unfortunately, I can not reproduce the situation, since I have not managed to get to a point, where anything happens.

Comment: You can't have a cross-database event trigger

Comment: "*I have the main database called main_db. In that one I create several databases*" - no you did not. You can not create a database inside a database. You can however create multiple _schemas_ inside a single database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you. I have removed that. So, have you any ideas for logging the creation and deletion of other DBS' tables in a table in another DB (preferably, automatically)?

Comment: To supplement the trigger mechanism discussed in Chapter 39, PostgreSQL also provides event triggers. Unlike regular triggers, which are attached to a single table and capture only DML events, event triggers are global to **a** particular database and are capable of capturing DDL events.